# Capybara and Rails, Why my link expected to return some thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, ruby-on-rails-plugins, capybara

I am trying to test that a link dose exist on the page,
I tried to check all the nesting tags that contain the link tag like that:

```
response.body.should have_selector("div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2")
```

and it passes correctly, but, if I added the link tag to the test like this:

```
  response.body.should have_selector("div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2 a",:text => "Next")
```

I get the error:

> expected css "div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2 a#next_page"
>   with text "Next" to return something

If I test it with have_link like this:

```
response.body.should have_link("div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2 a#next_page")
```

I get the error:

> expected link "div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2
>   a#next_page" to return something

Can any body help please ? I love rails, but, I still need a hand to get along with testing ..

**EDIT**

Here is the page.html, I've noticed that the html in content_for in which the link is rendered is not rendered in yield

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
<title></title>
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var auto_log_off = false;
//]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var student_logged = false;
//]]>
</script><script src="/assets/sessions.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- add your meta tags here --><link href="/assets/application_yaml/css/my_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lte IE 7]>  <![endif]--><link href="/assets/application_yaml/css/patch_my_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page_margins">
<a href="#dialog" name="modal"></a>
<div id="topnav">
<!-- start: skip link navigation -->
<a class="skip" href="#navigation" title="skip link">Skip to the navigation</a>
<span class="hideme">.</span>
<a class="skip" href="#content" title="skip link">Skip to the content</a>
<span class="hideme">.</span>
<!-- end: skip link navigation -->
</div>
<!-- start: skip link navigation -->
<!-- end: skip link navigation -->
<div class="page">
<div id="header">
<h1>Welcome to course builder!!</h1>
<p><a href="/" id="home_link">Home</a></p>
</div>
<div id="nav">
<!-- skiplink anchor: navigation -->
<a id="navigation" name="navigation"></a>
<div class="hlist">
<!-- main navigation: horizontal list -->

<div class="quiz_review_buttons">

<!--
<ul>
<li class="active"><strong>Button 1</strong></li>
<li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
</ul>
-->
</div>
<!-- <ul> -->
<!-- <li class="active"><strong>Button 1</strong></li> -->
<!-- <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li> -->
<!-- <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li> -->
<!-- <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li> -->
<!-- <li><a href="#">Button 5</a></li> -->
<!-- </ul> -->
</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="col1">
<div class="clearfix" id="col1_content">
<!-- add your content here -->

<div class="debug_div">
<p>
<b>
devise/sessions#new
</b>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="col3">
<div class="clearfix" id="col3_content">
<!-- add your content here -->
<div class="alert" id="notice_alert">You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.</div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script><!-- <div style="clear:both"></div> --><h2>Sign in for student</h2>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/students/sign_in" class="student_new" id="student_new" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
  <div>
<label for="student_email">Email</label><br><input id="student_email" name="student[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
</div>

  <div>
<label for="student_password">Password</label><br><input id="student_password" name="student[password]" size="30" type="password">
</div>

    <div>
<input name="student[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="student_remember_me" name="student[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1"><label for="student_remember_me">Remember me</label>
</div>

  <div><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in"></div>
</form>

  <a href="/students/sign_up">Sign up</a><br><a href="/students/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br>
</div>
<!-- IE Column Clearing -->
<div id="ie_clearing"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
Layout based on
<a href="http://www.yaml.de/">YAML</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, in controller specs, make sure you call render_views when checking markup.
.

Answer (score 2):

"expected to return something" just means that capybara couldn't find the element it was looking for. Hard to say why without seeing the html that capybara is searching

Note that the argument to `have_link` is not a css selector, it should be the text, id, title, or image alt attribute of the link.

Comment: as for the HTML that capybara is searching, its within this path:
div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2

how come capybara is able to find li#2 above but can't find 'a' inside li#2 ?

 response.body.should have_selector("div.page_margins div.page div#nav div.hlist ul li#2") is working fine, which leads to the parent of the link I am testing

is there restrictions regarding searching for a link in capybara ? maximum nesting depth ?

Comment: I've noticed that page.html dosen't include the html rendered via content_for, therefor, Capybara could't find the link, because its within the content_for html, so, any idea ? I've added an edit above to show you the page.html with empty yields